# Deploy image from aws ecr to aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecr

I am trying to deploy an docker image that I pushed to AWS ECR successfully.  However, when I try to deploy this image using Elastic Beanstalk, I am running into these issues.

- Application update failed at 2020-03-22T13:43:51Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh failed.
- jq: error (at :11): Cannot index array with string "Name"
  No Docker image specified in either Dockerfile or Dockerrun.aws.json. Abort deployment.
- Incorrect application version "v3" (deployment 4). Expected version "Sample Application" (deployment 1).

My Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 1,
  "Image": [{
    "Name": "############.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo-name:latest",
    "Update": "true"
  }],
  "Ports": [{
    "ContainerPort": "3030",
    "HostPort": "3030"
  }]
}
```

I believe I added the correct permissions but not sure.  I am noticing that the aws documentation is extensive but information is all over the place.  If anyone could help point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

So... make sure you don't set Image equal to an array... -_-